# Why am I unable to ping the same interface after configuring an IPv6 address

Tags: interface, ipv6, ping

I setup IPv6 in my Ubuntu 12.04 on eth0 using command

```
ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1/64
```

but when i try to ping `eth0` itself using

```
ping6 2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1
```

it always gives

```
PING 2001:db8:fedc:cdef:0:0:0:1(2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1)  56 data bytes
 From ::1 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
 From ::1 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
 From ::1 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

I think that it automatically is pinging from `::1` to `2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1

Command

```
ip addr show dev eth0
```

it gives

```
2: eth0:<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:38:a1:a2:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1/64 scope global tentative 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Command

```
ip -6 route
```

it gives

```
2001:db8:fedc:cdef::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

Command

```
ip6tables -L
```

it gives

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Command

```
ip6tables -F
it gives nothing.
```

Please help how to solve this.
this may have clue for someone

command

```
ip -6 route get 2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1
```

gives

```
2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1 from :: via 2001:db8:fedc:cdef::1 dev eth0  src ::1  metric 0 
cache
```

why it has src ::1 ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. My guess would be that your `eth0` interface is down. Please update your question with the output of `ip addr show dev eth0` and maybe `ip -6 route`.

Comment: Also check your ip6tables (run ip6tables -L). You may need to run ip6tables -F.

Comment: @celada  My eth0 interface is not down. i updated my question with required content.

Comment: `NO-CARRIER` is a little suspect though.

Comment: @Steve-o please how to solve this.

Comment: plug in a cable with a carrier signal.

Comment: @Steve-o as i m trying to ping the same interface so i unable to understand what is role of cable here. To be more clear i have another ubuntu 12.04 installed which is doing the same for me very well even it also has 
no-carrier

Comment: You are right. IPv6 address does work until you plug ethernet cable.
Thanks to alll for reply.

Comment: By the way, the same thing will happen with IPv4. You can ping localhost but you cannot ping the machine's IP on the interface when the interface is down or disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPv6 address is showing as `tentative` because duplicate address detection can't be completed. And the reason *that* can't happen is because you have no physical Ethernet connection (the link shows `NO-CARRIER`).

To resolve the issue, connect your Ethernet cable.

Comment: You are right. IPv6 address does work until you plug ethernet cable. Thanks to alll for reply.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 address range 2001:db8::/32 is reserved for documentation only and packets with these addresses should never exist on a network. All routers must discard packet with such addresses. Use another address range, e.g. Unique LocaL Addresses fd00::/8 (RFC 4193). If you want to get connection to internet, ask your provider for an ipv6-address-prefix.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful and not relevant to the question. Perhaps the O.P. was using the documentation prefix intentionally to make it suitable for posting on the internet? Give the benefit of the doubt here.