# Destination unreachable with ping6 between two local machines

Tags: networking, ipv6, ping

I have 2 Ubuntu machines one acting as IPv6 wireless router (running hostap and radvd on wlan0) and the other is connected to that router. the router `wlan0` interface has the address `2001:db8:1:1::1/64` and the host has the address `2001:db8:1:1::2/64` on `wlan0` which is connected to `ap1` provided by the router. On wireshark, I can see the router advertisements at the router and the host.

when I ping `2001:db8:1:1::2` at the router it says that `Destination unreachable: Address unreachable` and I can see the neighbour solicitation and advertisement messages exchange.

When I ping `2001:db8:1:1::1` at the host it says the same `Destination unreachable: Address unreachable` and I can see the neighbour solicitation message only.

Any idea?

Also, I have tried to do the following into the router

```
sudo ip -6 neigh add 2001:db8:1:1::2 lladdr 64:50:03:ec:cc:ss dev wlan0
sudo ip -6 neigh add 2001:db8:1:1::1 lladdr 64:50:03:ec:cc:ff dev wlan0
```

Then, when I ping I can see the echo request and reply exchange in wireshark only but I cannot see that at the command line, rather it says no packets have been received!

Comment: Your question sounds similar to http://askubuntu.com/q/256138/236, but they also look for a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

IPv6 address range 2001:db8::/32 is reserved for documentation only and packets with these addresses should never exist on a network. All routers must discard packet with such addresses. Use another address range, e.g. Unique LocaL Addresses fd00::/8 (RFC 4193). If you want to get connection to internet, ask your provider for an ipv6-address-prefix.